# Why do I have suggested edits to review, but there are none in the queue?

Tags: support, bug, suggested-edits

Look at this image:

[image: Suggested Edits]

That was on the [Gamification Stack Exchange](http://gamification.stackexchange.com) site. I have the ability to approve suggested edits that are proposed. This number sits at 4. However, whenever I click the lovely button, it leads me to an empty queue.

[image: Suggested Edit Queue]

Thinking that someone else may have reviewed them (and it must've been at a really nifty speed), I decided to let it go. However, the number won't go back. Instead, it goes up.

Could there be something wrong with this?

Comment: "This number sits at 4" for how long? Does it ever change? If so, how long does it sit at whatever number? Does it sometimes *not* show any number?

Comment: This has started maybe about 15 minutes ago. But I keep going to the queue and nothing pops up. A number is always shown, but it goes up sometimes. It goes up by 2 sometimes or by 1. Now it's at 5.